# Are Feynman's Hamiltonian computers unitary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

In this [paper](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/frs119/papers/feynman85_optics_letters.pdf), Feynman gave the idea of creating a time-independent Hamiltonian from a quantum circuit. Is there anyway to say that these Hamiltonians will always be Hermitian? Moreover, will these Hamiltonians be always unitary?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hamiltonian will always be Hermitian (as any Hamiltonian must). To see that this is true of Feynman's Hamiltonians, note that each term can be written in the form $h + h^\dagger$, where $h^\dagger$ denotes the Hermitian conjugate of $h$. Feynman indicates this by writing "+ complex conjugate", which is shorthand for what I just wrote. It is always true that $(h+h^\dagger)$ is Hermitian, since $(h+h^\dagger)^\dagger = h^\dagger+h = h+h^\dagger$, and therefore the whole Hamiltonian is Hermitian.

It is not true that Hamiltonians need to be unitary. Indeed, they generally are not unitary. What is unitary is the the time-evolution operator $U$. If the Hamiltonian is time-independent, they are related by $U(t) = e^{-iHt}$. The fact that $H$ is Hermitian necessarily implies that $U$ is unitary.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, Feynman was concerned with a physical system doing the actual computation, and all physical evolution is unitary, and hence the Hamiltonians must be unitary. A slight but trivial generalization would be to allow for evolution with completely positive maps, but such evolution can always be mimicked by unitary evolution with some auxiliary degrees of freedom followed by tracing out of those extra degrees of freedom.

Allowing for non-unitary evolutions would allow for very unphysical situations (signalling, ...) and would also allow quantum computers to solve NP-complete problems (which is certainly not expected to be possible)